# Cookies Getting expired after two three page refreshes

Tags: php, cookies

I have a page which remembers an user,if they login the first time and for the subsequent times they don't have to login again and again.

To achieve this i made an authentication class which contains various functions according to my needs.

Howvever, when i look for the cookie in my console , i cannot find the one which i created while the same cookie is seen in the header( white icon present near the hyperlink)

I will provide various screen shots to provide the same.

[image]

This one is just after i made a cookie, see, the same cookie value is not present in console but it is present above.

[image]

This one shows the expiry time of the cookie which is 30 days from today.It shouldn't expire, but on page refresh , it just vanishes.

[image]

It's just after one or two page refreshes,it's clearly visible that the cookie has been expired.

I'm totally baffled by this bizarre behavior.

```
public final function on_log($user,$user_name){
$token=$this->generate_random_token($user);
$this->store_token_for_user($user,$token);
$cookie = $user . ':' . $token;
$mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $cookie, $this->key);
$cookie .= ':' . $mac.':'.$user_name;
setcookie('_ajh_food_quo', $cookie,time() + (30 *24 * 60 * 60));//user cookie
//$this->logUserIn($user,$user_name);
}
```

Above function sets the cookie.

Could anyone please explain me, what am i doing wrong here?

If anyone needs something more please ask in the comments,i will update my question accordingly.

Comment: @downvoter care to answer?

Comment: I see that the path for your cookie is `/Google`. I don't know if this is how you want or not. If not add a 4th param to `setcookie` the path so should be like this: `setcookie('_ajh_food_quo', $cookie, time() + (30 *24 * 60 * 60), '/')` This way will be for all paths of the site..

Comment: @DanielDudas thanks a lot.It worked.You can answer the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for your cookie is `/Google`.

To make the session available on all the paths of your website  add a 4th param to `setcookie` the `/` path (root)

So it should be like this: `setcookie('_ajh_food_quo', $cookie, time() + (30 *24 * 60 * 60), '/')`

This way will be for all paths of the site..